# Error:XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dev...... Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to load html page in (dev.project.....com/app/views/index.html/#eprj/1) from another project(http://dev.media.....com/app/views/services/...) of my solution structure using $http method.But i am getting error:XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dev.media....com/app/views/services/tabs.html. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.

```
var mediaUrl = "http://dev.media....com/app/views/services"
var url = mediaUrl + '/tabs.html'
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
}).then(function (html) {
    // Convert the html to an actual DOM node
    var template = angular.element(html.data);
    // Append it to the directive element
    element.append(template);
    return $compile(element.contents())(scope);
});
```

The above code is written in AngularJs CustomDirective.

And Also in web.config of (http://dev.media....com) added inside system.webserver    tag as

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-Requested-With, origin, content-type, accept" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: Don't your forget to add tabs.html to your mediaUrl? If no, you sent wrong method (try post or put).

Comment: tabs.html added